# How to use a view to consolidate records in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, view, case, aggregate-functions

I'm wanting to create a view from a table of measurments. I want a consolidated record for each user in my table.  In the table I'm creating a view from each user can have 1 to N number of measurment records.  Each source has a type for various measurments that will have a priority over the other attributes.  How can I use an aggregate function to specify rules for determining which values to put in the consolidated record?  Or would it be a combination of aggregate functions and case statements?

**Sample Records**

```
userid  height   height_type,  weight,  weight_type,    recorded_date
1,      5'9",       'E',        200,        'E',        '2012-01-01'
1,      5'9",       'V',        195,        'E',        '2012-01-02'
1,      5'10",      'C',        195,        'V',        '2012-01-01'
2,      5'3",       'C',        144,        'C',        '2012-02-12'
2,      5'4",       'V',        147,        'E',        '2012-02-11'
3,      5'7",       'E',        144,        'E',        '2012-01-01'
```

**Prioritization for Records**

```
'C'=1,'V'=2,'E'=3
If they have the same type and different values then take the MAX() of the two
```

**Expected Results**

```
userid  height   height_type,  weight,  weight_type,    recorded_date
1,      5'10",      'C',        195,        'V',        '2012-01-02'
2,      5'3",       'C',        144,        'C',        '2012-02-12'
3,      5'7",       'E',        144,        'E',        '2012-01-01'
```

Comment: Please provide result for `1, 5', C, 200, V, 2012-01-01` vs `1, 6', V, 201, C, 2012-01-01`

Comment: `1, 5','C',201,'C', '2012-01-01'`  This make sense?

Comment: Also I messed up the expected results for user with id 3, I think I have it corrected above now, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be classic use of [ranking functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx). This query bring back right results:

```
;WITH Data (userid, height, height_type, weight, weight_type, recorded_date)
AS (
    SELECT 1, '5''9"', 'E', 200, 'E', '2012-01-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '5''9"', 'V', 195, 'E', '2012-01-02'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, '5''10"', 'C', 195, 'V', '2012-01-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '5''3"', 'C', 144, 'C', '2012-02-12'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, '5''4"', 'V', 147, 'E', '2012-02-11'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, '5''7"', 'E', 144, 'E', '2012-01-01'
    )
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY CASE weight_type WHEN 'C' THEN 1 WHEN 'V' THEN 2 WHEN 'E' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END, [weight] DESC) AS RN
    FROM Data
    ) AS T
WHERE T.RN = 1;
```

**Results:**

```
userid  height  height_type weight  weight_type recorded_date
-------------------------------------------------------------
1       5'10"   C           195     V           2012-01-01
2       5'3"    C           144     C           2012-02-12
3       5'7"    E           144     E           2012-01-01
```

This query will partition your data set by each UserID and order it by weight_type on given logic in ascending order and then by weight in descending order (`If they have the same type and different values then take the MAX() of the two`).

As a result it will generate `RN = 1` for required records.

Just wrap it up in a view. On top of that. I'd suggest creating computed column for weight_type for ordering. Then you could create index such as to boost performance of it:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_YourTable_UserID_ComputedWeightColumn_Weight_iHeight_iHeightType_iRecordedDate
    ON dbo.YourTable (UserID, ComputedWeightColumn, Weight DESC)
    INCLUDE (height, height_type, recorded_date);
```

Comment: How does this work when I need to prioritize different columns.  For instance with this method it works for weights -- but the optimal height might not be on the same row as a weight.

Comment: You need to think how to sort the optimal row as the first one for each user. This is business rules I guess. I don't know what would be the optimal height for weight? Perhaps you have to calculate BMI and use it ad secondary order parameter?